# Lint error with Fragments on Android L: "This method is not overriding anything"

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

[image: Error]

> This method is not overriding anything with the current build target,
>   but will in API level 11 (current target is 1).

How do I neutralize this error? The app compiles and runs. I'm using gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-L"
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codepath.apps.restclienttemplate"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion "android-L"
    }
    ....
}
```

According to to the [`<uses-sdk>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) docs, if `minSdkVersion` is absent it defaults to 1, so I'm thinking lint doesn't know what version is required.

Comment: Could you post the relevant portions of your Android Manifest?  Do you declare a minimum there?

Comment: Hi Robert. did you solve this issue? i have the exact same problem (with an addition of INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK). thanks

Comment: Same here. Weird that this doesn't happen if the `Fragment` is a static class within the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

1. download android-21 sdk from here: 
   https://mega.co.nz/#!klwQWQ6Z!seD3n0x9dkTyR29c7HxNE6XkHXtmpjfcbYrfntVOXmY
2. unzip it in you sdk path
3. in your gradle build file change this

compileSdkVersion "android-L"
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

to

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue on Android Studion **v0.8.0** (it was downloaded from official website, and it wasn't the latest version for that time (:sad) )

Just update the programm (Help ->  Check for Update...). In my case I updated to 0.8.6 and the issue has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that strings for API levels such as `android-L` or `L` resolves to `1` for the API level and it sees tons of methods that don't exist until later API levels (even very low API level methods added in 4 or 7).

Since the SDK is a preview and not final, I added this to my lint.xml file:

```
<!-- Android L pre-release disabled checks -->
<issue id="Override" severity="ignore"/>
```

Be sure to remove it once Android L's SDK is officially released and you can use `21` instead of a string.