# Android Studio thinks I'm building for API Level 1 instead of Android L

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

First things first, my app's gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blah.blah"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "alpha"
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.2.4'
}
```

Anyway, I have a `Fragment` for a `NavigationDrawer`, auto-generated by Android Studio, and all of the lifecycle methods (`onAttach()`, `onDetach()`, `onCreate()`, etc...) throw the error "This method is not overriding anything with the current build target, but will in API level 11 (current target is 1):". I have not touched the source for the fragment after Android Studio generated it. Why is this, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Same thing happening to me. But I can build and run the project just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you need minSdkVersion 'L' in preview as Araks points

but tt s a bug too, here a workaround
[Lint error with Fragments on Android L: "This method is not overriding anything"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463607/lint-error-with-fragments-on-android-l-this-method-is-not-overriding-anything)

Just happened me and my version is correct, looking for another solution...

Edited:
Niek Haarman uses minSdkVersion and says:
The minSdkVersion is set to 'L' automatically when building, to avoid releasing apps with preview features.
[Using Material theme on L preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439958/using-material-theme-on-l-preview)

Further information about the workaround:
http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2964nb/for_those_of_you_having_problems_building_with/

Answer (score 1):

first of all: are you running the latest Android Studio version (0.8.2)?

Secondly, when you want to build an app for Android L Developer Preview you must set the following values in your gradle.build file:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
minSdkVersion 'L'
targetSdkVersion 'L'
```

So, fix your minSdkVersion!

Source:
https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#createProject